# How can I figure out what causes unexpected reboot?

Tags: windows-10, reboot, windows-error-reporting

I have an Asus E200HA that keeps rebooting without warning. It happens perhaps every other day. In the beginning I suspected it was just Win 10 updates, but  Event View gives me critical errors from Kernel-Power. I also had a message about a reboot caused by BugCheck once.

I reinstalled Win 10 and drivers, but the problem did not go away. I did a memory test, but it says everything is ok.

Is there a way stress test the computer, or otherwise force this reboot to happen? I find no pattern that triggers it.

Furthermore, there seems to be a problem installing updates. Especially KB3200970 keeps failing (but I've had the reboot problem since april, way before this update.)